# Were cargo pods ever fitted to the original Cessna Caravan?

Tags: cessna-208

Cargo pods are available on the Grand Caravan (C208B and EX), as shown here:

[image]
*[Image source](https://www.airliners.net/photo/St-Barth-Commuter/Cessna-208B-Grand-Caravan/7072463)*

I'm trying to determine if cargo pods are (were?) fitted to the original (non-Grand) Caravan, either by the factory or a third party.  An internet search, including the Cessna website, did not turn up any examples.  However, I'm looking for a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they have.  I have flown one with them, here's a photo:

*(From the Wikipedia page for "Kenmore Air")*

[image]